# Iterating over features of a same layer

Tags: pyqgis-3, qgsvectorlayer

I have thousands of polygons in a layer. I am using following code to delete one of two intersecting polygons from a layer by checking geometry intersection of each polygon with all others. But it results in deleting both the intersecting polygons. How to delete only one instead of both? Also, this code is taking too long as there are many features in the layer. Is there any way to speed it up?

```py
features=[f for f in layer.getFeatures()]
layer.startEditing()
for n in features:
    geom = n.geometry()
    if any(geom.intersects(init.geometry())==True for init in features if n.id()!=init.id()):
        layer.deleteFeature(n.id())
layer.commitChanges()
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use `!=` (in `n.id()!=init.id()`) inside the "if" statement, you compare the items (ex: comparing 2 to 1)  you've compared before (ex: comparing 1 to 2). In this case, both items are deleted.

Use `<=` for `id` in the `if` statement like `if n.id() <= init.id())`. That also gives you a bit of speed. And using `any` in a such way is not reasonable. You probably will always get a `True` in your case.

**One critical suggestion**: Don't use `layer.deleteFeature` in editing mode, especially (1) in a `for` loop while comparing the features' ids in the same layer, especially (2) for a large dataset. That slows you down, and you may get unexpected results. Instead, use `layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures` as below:

```py
to_be_deleted = []
for n in layer.getFeatures():
    for init in layer.getFeatures():
        if n.id() <= init.id():
            g1 = n.geometry()
            g2 = init.geometry()           

            if g1.intersects(g2):
                to_be_deleted.append(n.id()) # or init.id()

layer.dataProvider().deleteFeatures(to_be_deleted)
```

Your question is not clear to me. But I think this answer gives you a hint.